# Jquery Toggle is not working on Iphone in responsive layout

Tags: jquery, css, iphone

i have this:

```
$(function(){
  $('.trigger').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().next('.detail').slideToggle();
 });
});
```

this happens inside a parent div:

```
.container {
z-index: 0;
margin-top: 450px; 
margin-top: 50vmin; 

margin-left: 25%;
margin-right: 25%;
width: 50%;

font-size: 2.7vmin; 
line-height: 3.3vmin;
}
```

on iphone safari this looks very bad - but only when I change the style of the parent container
in a media query.  (All the lines of the toggled div are messed up)

```
@media (max-width: 1100px) {

.container {

margin-top: 20px !important;
margin-bottom: 20px !important;

margin-left: 10%;
width: 80%;
margin-right: 10%

}
```

what can i do? thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you please provide your full code with jsfiddle? It will be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: it seems like "vmin" is making the problem, i change it to "px" and it looks better